# Azure Mobile App with Xamarin.Forms - the second call doesn't go to server

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I have a Xamarin.Forms app that uses Azure Mobile SDK with Sqlite (I did my test on Android).

For the backend I use Azure Mobile App. Controllers that talk directly with the app are very simple, just the standard implementation class from `TableController<T>`. No authentication (yet) implemented.

I created the client:

```
var client = new MobileServiceClient("http://...", new LoggingHandler());
```

Where LoggingHandler inherit from DelegatingHandler, and has:

```
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Request: {request.Method} {request.RequestUri}");
        ...
    }
```

The same table, is synchronized in different point, like this:

```
await table.PullAsync(queryName, query);
```

The first time, no problem. `SendAsync()` in `LoggingHandler` is called, table is synch. 
In another part of the program, I call the same line and the app gets stuck. No exception throw, `SendAsync()` in `LoggingHandler` is not called. The execution gets stuck in `PullAsync()`. 
Any clue?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to go on.  This is certainly not normal, so there must be more to your application.  The only thing I can suggest is download the SDK symbols and step through the code - see where it actually freezes.

Comment: Smells like a deadlock. You'll need to provide more information. How exactly are you calling the method that contains the call to `PullAsync()`?